# What is the byproduct from hydrogenolysis of an acyl chloride?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox

What's the byproduct of this reaction? After all, it is a "lysis" reaction. So ... would HCl be a byproduct?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to this reaction? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenmund_reduction

Comment: @bon yes. Same reaction. Prof forgot the name

Answer (score 5):

Yes HCl is a byproduct of the Rosenmund reduction.

[image]

http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/rosenmund-reduction.shtm